# Regenerate JWT bearer token on each API request

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jwt

I want to regenerate my bearer token on each request being made to the server.

I do not want to use refresh token for this purpose.

Can someone please advise how I can regenerate a new token with new expiration stamp from the earlier token generated which is being passed through the authorization header?

Comment: For what purpose if I may ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a MessageHandler filter inheriting from DelegatingHandler class and overwrote SendAsync method.

I can have access to my original bearer token received from the request here which I can decode and generate a new one. After generating a new one I dump it to the response so that this will execute on every request and we don't need to manage individual API

```
        string audienceId = Properties.Settings.Default.AudienceId;
        var issuer = Properties.Settings.Default.AngularHostURL;
        string symmetricKeyAsBase64 = Properties.Settings.Default.AudienceSecret;

        DateTime IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DateTime ExpiresUtc = 
        IssuedUtc.AddMinutes(Properties.Settings.Default.TokenLifetimeInMinutes);
        var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(symmetricKeyAsBase64);
        var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(keyByteArray);

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("JWT");

        foreach (var claim in claims)
            identity.AddClaim(claim);

        var tokennew = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer, audienceId, identity.Claims, 
        IssuedUtc, ExpiresUtc, signingKey);
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var jwt = handler.WriteToken(tokennew);

        return jwt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the token endpoint of the Authorization Server each time before you make an API request.

Comment: I don't want to make addtional request. I am trying to generate token on each call the to web server and new token will be send in response mesasage. I am looking for sliding expiration token

Comment: ok, the words you use suggested OAuth 2.0 hence my answer; seems you're looking to do something else than a standard

Comment: I did something identical to what you suggest but instead of calling endpoint each time I made generic response in each API call which will have new token with extended validity